# Why is my register_shutdown_function() not working with namespaces?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    namespace joe;

    function shutdown()
    {
            if(is_null($e = error_get_last()) === false)
            {
                    mail('bili@web.de', 'Error from auto_prepend', print_r($e, true));
            }
    };

    register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
    ...
```

With this lines I will get the error:

> Warning: register_shutdown_function(): Invalid shutdown callback
>   'shutdown' passed in /www/...

If I delete my namespace it works like a charm.
Whats wrong??

Comment: `register_shutdown_function('joe\\shutdown');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my 'shutdown callback ' invalid when using register\_shutdown\_function()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881034/why-is-my-shutdown-callback-invalid-when-using-register-shutdown-function)

Comment: thx to naththedeveloper. It seems that I did not understand the namespace stuff. I have seen the duplicate marked answer before. But I did'nt see the context.